# Multiple CheckBoxes Posting Data Filtering Issue

Tags: php, html, joomla, checkbox

I have a form as shown below.

[image: checkbpxes]

What I have done up to now is assign a checkbox for each item as follows.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="relevant_value" class="checks">
```

Now my issue is I can not figure out which the parent item and which is the child item. How can I solve this?

(Given I use Joomla. Get the checkboxes using below code)

```
$options    = JRequest::getVar('options', NULL, 'post', 'array');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest to use multidimensional array.like this-

```
For parent-
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="parent" class="checks">
For child-
<input type="checkbox" name="options[parent][]" value="child" class="checks">
```

get data through-

```
$options    = JRequest::getVar('options', NULL, 'post', 'array');
```

see how data comes-

```
print_r($options);
```

Now it's two dimentional,use parent as the key for child to differentiate different parent.

```
foreach($options as $option){
         $parent[] = $option;
         if(is_array($options[$option]){
             foreach($options[$option] as $opt)
             $childs[$option][]=$opt;
         }

    }
```

let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: How can I retrive at the backend? get which parents and childs are checked

Answer (score 1):

You should use array like this :

```
<!-- parent -->
<input type="checkbox" name="options[group_id]" value="relevant_value" class="checks">
```

and

```
<!-- associated child-->
<input type="checkbox" name="options[group_id][values][]" value="relevant_value" class="checks">
```

Retrieving associative values will be more easy this way

Comment: How can I retrive at the backend? get which parents and childs are checked

Comment: $options    = JRequest::getVar('options', NULL, 'post', 'array');
 and iterate over this with a foreach : 
 foreach($options as $option) {
 //$option is your parent. And iterate over your values : 
 foreach ($options['values'] as $value) {
  //$value is your associated value
 }
 })